# Jquery change text and css for part of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

To simplify, I have a label set in my html as:

```
 <label id ="lblApptDateTime" >Appointment</label>
```

On an event I am changing the lext of lblApptDateTime to Appointment with an asterisk. I want the asterisk to be red color and in bold font. How do i achieve that ?

Here's what I am changing the text on the event:

```
  $("#lblApptDateTime").html("Appointment" + "*");
```

Need to change the color of asterisk to red and in bold font.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the asterisk in an `:after` pseudo-element. This way you can style it to your liking, apart from the text.

```
.asterisk:after {
    content: '*';
    color: red;
}
```

In your JavaScript, instead of adding the asterisk inside the label, you just add the class `asterisk` to it:

```
$("#lblApptDateTime").html("Appointment").addClass("asterisk");
```

You can also use `toggleClass()` instead of `addClass()` if the asterisk should be toggle-able.

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12148/). Since I didn't have any other event available, I used `hover`.

Comment: better still just to add a classname.  $("#lblApptDateTime").addClass('asterisked'); for css #lblApptDateTime.asterisked:after {...}

Comment: Yes. Very good point. Adding a class can always be toggled, so it adds flexibility. I'll update it with wwwmarty's suggestion.

Comment: i tried your way Andrei ...it colors the whole text red. I just wanted the asterisk to be color red.

Comment: #lblApptDateTime.asterisk:after {
    content: '*';
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

Comment: I will create a jsFiddle with this. And update the answer. Hold on.

Comment: I added a working fiddle. If it doesn't in your live case, you must be missing some small detail. Make a fiddle with it and (hopefully) I will spot the missing part.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it in a span and use a class

```js
$("#lblApptDateTime").html('Appointment' + '<span class="red">*</span>');
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="lblApptDateTime">Appointment</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
$("#lblApptDateTime").html("Appointment" + "<span class="red">*</span>");
```

CSS:

```
span.red {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to put it in a new styled element like a `span`, which you can do with `append`:

```
$("#lblApptDateTime").append($("<span>").css("color", "red").text("*"));
```

Or `addClass()` instead of using `css()` and style it appropriately.